# IIS failed to load website after heavy load

Tags: iis

I am having problem with my website on Windows Server 2012 R2 IIS 8.5. During heavy traffic the service "World Wide Web Publishing" still running but it will shows "500 Internal Server Error". Once I restarted the the service "World Wide Web Publishing", the website will be back to normal. May I know why is this happening and how to fix this problem?

The website I want to view just a few SQL select command but it will refresh every 5 seconds. User will login to the screen and it will reload to display new info onto the PC screen. It is a website to show latest Production Job but >50 PCs will access the server concurrently and auto refresh every 5 seconds.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0 If you can see 500.0 in IIS logs, then it is your web app that reports the issue, and very likely it cannot handle such load. Your description above shows possible inefficient usage of database connections. You might run a performance profiler to learn more.

Comment: I have checked the Event Viewer and I guess it is due to my connection was not closed. I already amend the website and now testing on it.